# Orthogonal Channels in a RAKE receiver?

Tags: electrical-engineering, wireless-communication

Can I use the delay of different paths of a RAKE receiver for orthogonal channels. The idea is that if I have a square law detector for a packet of bits there will be no channel interference because the delay effectively acts as a pad of zeros. It's a technique that I want to use? If there are any papers on this I would greatly appreciate it.